# What does `app.use(bodyParser.json())` do?

Tags: json, express, body-parser

For:

```
bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: ...})
```

my research shows me that if `extended: true`, then you can parse nested objects, or generally any type. However, if you set `extended: false`, then you can only parse strings or arrays. But what does ...

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

mean exactly? I mean, yes... I know the docs mention that it parses json. But I am still confused. I have noticed applications that set `extended: true` do NOT use `bodyParser.json()` at all. But applications that `extended: false` tend to use `bodyParser.json()`. Why is this? At the end of the day, both applications are able to parse json.

Secondly, which is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Okay, contrary to what I previously thought, further research shows that `extended: true` and `app.use(bodyParser.json())` can be used together. So it is not only `extended: false` that uses it. The statement `app.use(bodyParser.json())` is to be used independently, whether you set extended as `true` or `false`.

- `app.use(bodyParser.json())` basically tells the system that you want json to be used.
- `bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: ...})` basically tells the system whether you want to use a simple algorithm for shallow parsing (i.e. false) or complex algorithm for deep parsing that can deal with nested objects (i.e. true).

Have a look at the docs (i.e. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html) for the example.

Answer (score 9):

URL encoding and JSON encoding both allow to convert a (nested) object to string, but the format is different. An URL encoded string is in general not a valid JSON string.

One application may use one encoding method, and another the other. As long as they don't mix the two, it will work.

Comment: Can one application set extended as true and yet still have `app.use(bodyParse.json())`? Or does the latter always go with extended being false? But interestingly, both seem to work for json parsing.

Answer (score 7):

`bodyParser.json` returns middleware that only parses JSON. This parser accepts any Unicode encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. `req.body`).