# Passing the params using react fetch not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Here's the server controller (which works)

```
function logTheRequest(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

Here's the client side fetch

```
newCustomer() {
  fetch('/customers/sign-up', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'test',
  });
}
```

But when I console.log(req.body), all I get is { }

Comment: I think that it might expect json. Did you try to pass a contentType header (of 'application/text') ?

Comment: Just tried it with   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/text'
  }, and it's still showing body { }. Thank you for offering a suggestion! :)

Comment: You might have a wrong nodejs configuration then. Check the network tab and see if the data was sent properly.

Comment: Should I make an issue on the github repo? It's react-starter-kit. Works with application/json, but not application/text

Comment: Im pretty sure the stack is intended to work with json, so there is no issue. If you wish to change it to text you need to adjust it.

Comment: If you are using - https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit, then check https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/server.js. it has this line of configuration : app.use(bodyParser.json());

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` kept coming back empty for me until I added `app.use(bodyParser.json()` into my `server.js` file. Make sure you import `body-parser`.

Looks like the reason is because bodyParser parses request bodies in middleware under `req.body`: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser. More details on bodyParser: [What does `app.use(bodyParser.json())` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870867/what-does-app-usebodyparser-json-do).